# Prevent Jface wizard list resize window after items adding

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have such wizard list:

```
list = new List(sashForm2, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

if my list is empty the general wizard window has normal size. But after adding some items:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    fTypeArrayList.add(new FirstTypeMD(new Random().nextInt(2000) + 500, new Random().nextInt(2000),
            new Random().nextInt(200) + 20, new Random().nextBoolean(), new Random().nextBoolean(),
            new Random().nextInt(200)));

    sTypeArrayList.add(new SecondTypeMD(new Random().nextInt(2000) + 500, new Random().nextInt(2000),
            new Random().nextInt(200) + 20, new Random().nextBoolean(), new Random().nextBoolean(),
            new Random().nextInt(200) + 5, new Random().nextInt(100) + 5));

    thTypeArrayList.add(new ThirdTypeMD(new Random().nextInt(2000) + 500, new Random().nextInt(2000),
            new Random().nextInt(200) + 20, new Random().nextBoolean(), new Random().nextBoolean(),
            new Random().nextInt(3) + 1, new Random().nextInt(3) + 1));

    FirstTypeMD fModeMd = fTypeArrayList.get(i);
    SecondTypeMD sModeMd = sTypeArrayList.get(i);
    ThirdTypeMD thModeMd = thTypeArrayList.get(i);

    list.add("T0 ---> " + fModeMd.energyCons + " " + fModeMd.framePerSec + " " + fModeMd.mass + " "
            + fModeMd.tempRange);
    list.add("T1 ---> " + sModeMd.energyCons + " " + sModeMd.speed + " " + sModeMd.sensorAmount + " "
            + sModeMd.mass + " " + sModeMd.tempRange);

    list.add("T2 ---> " + thModeMd.energyCons + " " + thModeMd.displayDiff + " " + thModeMd.dataProcess + " "
            + thModeMd.mass + " " + thModeMd.tempRange);

}
```

my wizard window height is bigger than Eclipse one. I tried to add some layout sizing:

```
list.setSize(100, 300);
```

and also smth like that:

```
GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true);
gridData.verticalSpan = 4;
int listHeight = list.getItemHeight() * 12;
Rectangle trim = list.computeTrim(0, 0, 0, listHeight);
gridData.heightHint = trim.height;
list.setLayoutData(gridData);
```

but it didn't help me to solve this problem. Maybe I did smth wrong? Maybe I have to set fixed size for its container:

```
SashForm sashForm = new SashForm(control, SWT.CENTER);
SashForm sashForm2 = new SashForm(sashForm, SWT.VERTICAL);
```

As you can see I have to sashforms one inside another. Logic was approved but size causes some visual difficulties for users :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list appears to be a direct child of `SashForm`. `SashForm` does not use `GridLayout` so setting `GridData` layout data on the list has no effect. Calling the `setSize` method also doesn't work because `SashForm` will set the size according to its own calculations.

You could try adding a `Composite` as the direct child of the `SashForm`. Add the list as the child of that `Composite`. Set `GridLayout` as the layout of the `Composite` and then the `GridData.heightHint` should be used.

Maybe something like the following (not tested):

```
Composite form2Comp = new Composite(sashForm2, SWT.NONE);
form2Comp.setLayout(new GridLayout());

list = new List(form2Comp, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);

GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
data.heightHint = ....
list.setLayoutData(data);
```

Comment: can you add some small code example please, because I'm newbie and can do it on wrong way :)